# How to find the inverse of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

How to find the inverse of the matrix? I am not asking for doing adjoint by determinant. Is there any other easy way to  do it?

> > \begin{pmatrix}
> > 1 & 0 & 0 &0 &0\\
> > 0 & 1 & 0 &0 &0\\
> > 0 & 0 & 1 &0 &0\\
> > 0 & 0 & 2 &1 &0\\ 0&0&3&0&1
> > \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Row reduce the matrix to the identity matrix keeping track of your operations, applying the same operations (in the same order) on the identity matrix yields the inverse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix

Comment: With this particular matrix, you can pretty much do it by hand simply putting the unknown inverse on the right and working through multiplying by the top row, second row etc.

Comment: For block matrices you can check that $\begin{bmatrix}I & \\ X & I\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}I & \\ -X & I\end{bmatrix}$, where the $I$'s represent identity matrices (of any sizes), and $X$ is any matrix that "fits".

Comment: Is that an observation?

Answer (score 8):

*Hint:* Your matrix is $A=I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent.

*Solution:*

> We have $N^2=0$ and so $A(I-N)=I$. Therefore, $A^{-1}=I-N$.

Answer (score 3):

You can "attach" an identity matrix $I_5$ use the Gauss-Jordan method until on the left-side you have the identity matrix and the right side you have an inverse matrix